# Sensitivity and Specficity (Conditional Probability problem)

Tags: probability, statistics

A medical diagnostic test with sensitivity (true positive rate) of
.95 and specificity (true negative rate) of .90. The disease in question is rare
and occurs in the population with the probability 1/10,000 . A patient is
diagnosed with the disease.
Given the diagnosis, what is the probability that the patient actually has the
disease?

I understand how to determine the True Positive Rate and the True Negative Rate with their specific equations, however i am unsure as to how find the final probability.

Thank you

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Let B be positive diagnosis.

Let A be person is sick.

$$P(A|B)= \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)} = \frac{0.0001\cdot0.95}{0.0001\cdot0.95+ 0.9999\cdot0.1}\approx 0.000949$$

Comment: You have made a mistake in line 2

Comment: @RowanS No. Looking to your answer, the difference is 0.1 versus 0.05. But the question says, that there is a true negative rate of 0.90. Therefore the test gives a positive rate while the person is healthy in 0.10 of the cases.

Comment: I meant the previous line

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

$p(a|b)=p( a \quad \text{and} \quad b) / p(b)$

$= 0.0001*0.95 / (0.0001*0.95 + 0.9999*0.1)$

Comment: Please use LaTeX to write down your math.

Comment: If I changed your intention, then please, try to write it in LaTeX yourself, or your answer might downvoted. (I'll give it another try)

Comment: You've butchered my answer so it is now wrong but I don't seem to be able to roll back.

Comment: I rolled it back to your original version per your request.

Comment: I am an infrequent visitor. I am curious to know  why  LaTeX (MathJax?) is so essential for a simple formula which can be easily understood ?

Comment: @trueblueanil. You make an excellent point. For more complicated formulas LaTeX is truly helpful, sometimes absolutely essential. But no reasonable person could misunderstand this Answer. Some visitors to this site seem to value elegant LaTeX above substance.